# Sites disappear when changing position in your sites

Tags: bug, android-app

When changing the position of sites in the your site menu of the app, sites disappear when a site is moved above them. It's only the edit ui as the sites still exist in the normal menu. I'm using a Galaxy S5.

> [image: Picture of Bug]

[full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCoeZ.jpg)